# Dynamic URL Redirect for SharePoint

Tags: javascript, html, infopath

I have an InfoPath Form (published on SharePoint) with a workflow that emails users for approval, now my problem is if the user is not already signed-in on the intranet then the form does not load for approval. The form only loads if a user already has the Intranet Site Open.

I want to solve the issue by embedding code on the link emailed to users for approval. The code should load the Home.aspx intranet page first, then after a few seconds redirect the user to the form for approval.

The link emailed to users is dynamic and is passed as follow:

string link = "E-Form";

Is this possible? How should I proceed?

Please help, and let me know if you need clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are seeking to create a link that passes a Query string value in the approval link to the user? Why not use a custom workflow?

David Sterling
www.sterling-consulting.com